# Counting - Multiplication principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This is an exercise from the book *Discrete Mathematics* by Gary Chartrand and Ping Zhang.

A student is preparing to go to class on a winter morning. He has three coats, four sweaters and two hats. How many possibilities does he have of what to wear if he must wear a coat?

The solution in the book is $3.5.3 = 45$.

But it doesn't make any to me. Shouldn't the answer be $3.4.2 = 24$?!

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Can he wear two sweaters at the same time?

Comment: @lulu I just edited the question

Comment: The problem specifies that he must wear a coat, which suggests that he need not wear a sweater or a hat.

Comment: @lulu You meant to say that he need not wear a sweater or a hat.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  What an odd typo.  Thanks, will edit now.

Comment: As a way to speed the counting (by avoiding casework):  add an option to each of the sweater and hat groups.  That option would then correspond to "None".